# Check if Instagram profile is private without authentication

Tags: php, api, instagram

Is there a way to way to determine if a profile is private or public based on the public profile page it has on http://instagram.com/username.

I know there are ways but all of them require CLIENT_ID which I am not talking of. I need a way to differentiate private & public profile just from the source of the profile webpage.

I don't mind if it requires scraping data off Instagram.

Answer (score 2):

If instagram profile is private, web page will contain this text: `"is_private":true`

So to determine is account private without `client_id` do something like this:

```
    $instagramPage = strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/raiym'));
    if (strpos($instagramPage,'"is_private":true') !== false) {
        return 'Account is private';
    } else {
        return 'Account is public';
    }
```

Or you can use php library: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper

```
$instagram = new Instagram();
$account = $instagram->getAccount('kevin');
if ($account->isPrivate) {
    echo 'Account is private';
} else {
    echo 'Account is public';
}
```

Comment: Writing it here for other users who read it: this doesn't work anymore (2022)